# Stop websites to redirect to their Play store apps

Tags: google-play-store, chrome-for-android

Some websites force to install their app and won't let me visit their websites in Google chrome on Android without redirecting to playdate
Play store. Only workaround is incognito mode because chrome won't "break out" of it.

Instant apps are disabled. "Default app" is disabled for the Play store.

This is an example:
https://castbox.fm/vb/409788348

Any way to disable it?
Thanks

Comment: Are you willing to change browser? This problem doesn't exist in Mozilla Firefox. Firefox offers a toggle "Open links in apps" in its settings.

Comment: Unfortunately because of Chrome / Google account sync ;-(

Answer (score 0):

Just disable that fncking google play store

Comment: Hmmm, very good idea :D